# mongoose cast error with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save a new user and add some group as a reference.
The group is loaded from database.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, 'default': '', index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
    password: String,
    accessToken: String,
    registerDate: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now},
    groups: [{type: ObjectId, ref:'Group'}]
});


var groupSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, 'default': '', index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}}
});


exports.register = function(req, res, next){
    var userToRegister = req.body;
    var newUser = new User();
    Group.find({name:"User"}, function(err, group){
        if(err){
            res.send("no User-group found");
        }
        newUser.set('groups', [group]);
        newUser.set('email', userToRegister.email);
        newUser.set('password', userToRegister.password);
        newUser.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.end("error at saving user", 500);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify(newUser));
        });

    });
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
message "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 52f6b49e13bdfa901b5a64d3, __v: 0, name... (length: 108)" 
name    "CastError" 
path    "groups"    
stack   undefined   
type    "ObjectId"
```

As I can see, it is a valid ObjectId. So where could be the error?

---

Solution:

using:   Group.findOne(...)
or:      newUser.set('groups', [group[0]]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.find returns array. use group[0] or use findOne().

`newUser.set('groups', [group[0]]);`

Comment: when I use new User({... groups:[userGroup], ...}); it works?

Comment: a group which i load from database

Comment: `ref` in mongoose works just like sql table joins. You store the id of the other collection in one collection. All you need to do is store the group ids.

Comment: when i want to set the id i get : Cast to non_object_property_load failed for value "" at path "groups". But group is not null. It is: { _id: 52f6b49e13bdfa901b5a64d3, __v: 0, name: 'User' }

Comment: maybe because there is no group named "User" `Group.find({name:"User"}`. fire up mongo console and check your query there - `db.Group.find({name:"User"})`

Comment: it is there.  { _id: 52f6b49e13bdfa901b5a64d3, __v: 0, name: 'User' }.

Comment: .find returns an array. use group[0] to get to the group. Or better use findOne.

Comment: argh. Thats the error ;-). Thanks! BTW: It now works also without setting the it. I can set the group-object directly.

Comment: Yes i saw the documentation and changed the answer accordingly.